# UIActivityViewController mixing text and images and keeping the order

Tags: ios, sms, mms, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to mix images and text and send them as MMS? `UIActivityViewController` will share an image with text underneath, but no matter how I order the text and images, the images always appear on top and the text on the bottom. If it's not possible with `UIActivityViewController`, is there another way?

The code I'm trying to use:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[smallImage, @"Love", mediumImage, @"You", largeImage];
NSArray *applicationActivities = nil;
NSArray *excludeActivities = nil;

UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**It produces this result:**
[image: Result produced]

**But this is what I want:**
[image: What I want]

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solutions? I have the same issue. I  need to know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I haven' found any solutions yet. I'm still having the same issue. I'm sorry!

Comment: Bump. Having the same issue. If I use an attributed string, the image doesn’t show up.